# How can I create an edge-split modifier within geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to be able to split edges by angle within geometry nodes.

I have already tried the *Edge Angle* node connected to a *Compare* (greater than) but I can't seem to get it to work. It somehow splits random edges.

And another related question.
I have some edges along a completely flat face. How can I remove those within geometry nodes?

Comment: please open another post for your second question. You should ask only one question per post because other users cannot find your second question and cannot learn from that. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you are:

[image]

result:

[image]

remember: the angles used by GN are in radians!